Terrible brightness range and inverted brightness buttons on integrated display Endeavour OS
The integrated display cannot go over above 50% brightness and buttons for changing it are inverted. I believe this is a well-known issue on HP Victus laptops - but it was never solved, not in the slightest. So I wonder if there is any idea to do something about it - I believe it is not EOS specific issue, as it persists on pure Arch and Ubuntu - is it possible to lock brightness on a hardware level? Or perhaps any workaround. Any help appreciated.

Update:
I belive there is a workaround to force the highest possible brightness:
step 1: sudo nano /etc/default/grub
step 2: edit this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor" (on ubuntu, on arch simply add acpi_backlight=vendor part at the end of other arguments)
step 3: sudo update-grub ("# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg" on arch)
This forces highest possible brightness, with no way to change it, but you can revert by changing the file back.
step 4: sudo reboot
